# Redirect to a WebPage while Adding a Custom Request Header

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, custom-headers

I have to redirect to new webpage from my site. In addition to the redirection, I have to set a custom header.

Any idea how to accomplish this in JavaScript or Asp.net?

Comment: HTTP headers are valid only for the current response. When you set a redirect the current response contains your custom header but when the browser follows the redirect location those headers are no longer present. Furthermore if you are using Request["id"] in the other page so you need to sent the value as query string:
`Response.Redirect("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?id=test");`

Comment: I understand all that. I don't want to pass the value in the query string, hence the header. I'm asking if anyone knows of away to accomplish this using JavaScript or ASP.net.

Comment: you want to set the custom header in the `redirected` page, but that title will be passed from `redirecting` page? is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. I need to set the header in the request object

Comment: then you can use the `session` , just add the header in the `redirected` page and append that session to the cs code in `redirecting` page using the Page.Title